# How do I know if a thread is a dummy thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, apache2, apache2.4

My basic question is: how do I detect whether the current thread is a dummy thread? I am new to threading and I recently was debugging some code in my Apache2/Flask app and thought it might be useful. I was getting a flip flopping error where a request was processed successfully on the main thread, unsuccessfully on a dummy thread and then successfully on the main thread again, etc.

Like I said I am using Apache2 and Flask which seems the combination of which creates these dummy threads. I would also be interested in knowing more about that if anyone can teach me.

My code is meant to print information about the threads running on the service and looks something like this:

```
def allthr_info(self):
    """Returns info in JSON form of all threads."""
    all_thread_infos = Queue()
    for thread_x in threading.enumerate():
        if thread_x is threading.current_thread() or thread_x is threading.main_thread():
            continue
        info = self._thr_info(thread_x)
        all_thread_infos.put(info)

    return list(all_thread_infos.queue)

def _thr_info(self, thr):
    """Consolidation of the thread info that can be obtained from threading module."""
    thread_info = {}
    try:
        thread_info = {
            'name': thr.getName(),
            'ident': thr.ident,
            'daemon': thr.daemon,
            'is_alive': thr.is_alive(),
        }
    except Exception as e:
        LOGGER.error(e)
    return thread_info
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the current thread is an instance of `threading._DummyThread`.

```
isinstance(threading.current_thread(), threading._DummyThread)
```

`threading.py` itself can teach you what dummy-threads are about:

> Dummy thread class to represent threads not started here.
>   These aren't garbage collected when they die, nor can they be waited for.
>   If they invoke anything in threading.py that calls current_thread(), they
>   leave an entry in the _active dict forever after.
>   Their purpose is to return *something* from current_thread().
>   They are marked as daemon threads so we won't wait for them
>   when we exit (conform previous semantics).
>
> ```
> def current_thread():
>     """Return the current Thread object, corresponding to the caller's thread of control.
>
>     If the caller's thread of control was not created through the threading
>     module, a dummy thread object with limited functionality is returned.
>
>     """
>     try:
>         return _active[get_ident()]
>     except KeyError:
>         return _DummyThread()
> ```